# Convert result of aggregation into 3 separate fields of col name, aggregate function and value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate

I have a dataframe in the form

```
+-----+--------+-------+
| id  | label  | count |
+-----+--------+-------+
| id1 | label1 |     5 |
| id1 | label1 |     2 |
| id2 | label2 |     3 |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

and I would like the resulting output to look like

```
+-----+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| id  | label  | col_name | agg_func | value |
+-----+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| id1 | label1 | count    | avg      |   3.5 |
| id1 | label1 | count    | sum      |     7 |
| id2 | label2 | count    | avg      |     3 |
| id2 | label2 | count    | sum      |     3 |
+-----+--------+----------+----------+-------+
```

First, I created a list of aggregate functions using the code below. I then apply these functions into the original dataframe to get the aggregation results in separate columns.

```scala
val f = org.apache.spark.sql.functions
val aggCols = Seq("col_name")
val aggFuncs = Seq("avg", "sum")
val aggOp = for (func <- aggFuncs) yield {
aggCols.map(x => f.getClass.getMethod(func, x.getClass).invoke(f, x).asInstanceOf[Column])
}
val aggOpFlat = aggOp.flatten

df.groupBy("id", "label").agg(aggOpFlat.head, aggOpFlat.tail: _*).na.fill(0)
```

I get to the format

```
+-----+--------+---------------+----------------+
| id  | label  | avg(col_name) |  sum(col_name) |
+-----+--------+---------------+----------------+
| id1 | label1 |           3.5 |              7 |
| id2 | label2 |             3 |              3 |
+-----+--------+---------------+----------------+
```

but cannot think of the logic to get to what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution might be to wrap all the aggregate values inside a [map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#map-scala.collection.Seq-) and then to use [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) function.

Something like that (shouldn't be an issue to make it dynamic).

```
val df = List ( ("id1", "label1", 5), ("id1", "label1", 2), ("id2", "label2", 3)).toDF("id", "label", "count")


df
.groupBy("id", "label")
.agg(avg("count").as("avg"), sum("count").as("sum"))
.withColumn("map", map( lit("avg"), col("avg"), lit("sum"), col("sum")))
.select(col("id"), col("label"), explode(col("map")))
.show
```